# How to read binary files in node js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to fetch content of a binary file in binary format. but i think I doing something wrong. can anyone help?

**Code Sample**

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.open('public/abc.bin', 'r', function(status, fd) {
    if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        return;
    }
    var buffer = new Buffer(100);
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 100, 0, function(err, num) {
        response['msg'] = buffer.toString('utf-8', 0, num);
        res.json(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: what kind of error you are having? could you add the output?

Comment: why do you convert binary buffer to utf-8?